# σ-algebra generated by a set of random variables vs σ-algebra generated by random vector

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X\colon (\Omega,\mathscr{F}) \to (M,\mathscr{M})$ and $Y\colon (\Omega,\mathscr{F}) \to (N,\mathscr{N})$ be two random variables. We can think of the vector $Z=(X,Y)$ as a random variable $Z \colon (\Omega,\mathscr{F}) \to (M\times N,\mathscr{M} \otimes \mathscr{N})$.

Let $\mathscr{A}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra jointly generated by $X$ and $Y$, i.e. the smallest $\sigma$ algebra in which both are measurable, and let $\mathscr{B}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Z$. When is it the case the $\mathscr{A}=\mathscr{B}$?

I guess it is so when $M=N=\Re$ and the $\mathscr{M}$ and $\mathscr{N}$ are the Borel $\sigma$-algebras. But is it also true more generally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are always equal. $\sigma (Z)=\{Z^{-1} (E): E \in \mathcal M \otimes \mathcal N\}$ and this is same as the sigma algebra generated by $\{Z^{-1} (A \times B): A \in \mathcal M , B \in \mathcal N\}$. And this last sigma algbera is the one generated by $X$ and $Y$.